# React Native + mySQL - fetching data in my App

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, native

I have a local database with myPHPadmin and I used the following Code:

```
// This is the routes.js file!

const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mysql = require('mysql');

const connection = mysql.createPool({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'me',
  password : 'secret',
  database : 'my_db'
});
// We're still in routes.js! Right below everything else.

// Starting our app.
const app = express();

// Creating a GET route that returns data from the 'users' table.
app.get('/users', function (req, res) {
    // Connecting to the database.
    connection.getConnection(function (err, connection) {

    // Executing the MySQL query (select all data from the 'users' table).
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM users', function (error, results, fields) {
      // If some error occurs, we throw an error.
      if (error) throw error;

      // Getting the 'response' from the database and sending it to our route. This is were the data is.
      res.send(results)
    });
  });
});

// Starting our server.
app.listen(3000, () => {
 console.log('Go to http://localhost:3000/users so you can see the data.');
});
```

From this site: https://dev.to/saulojoab/how-to-get-data-from-an-mysql-database-in-react-native-53a4

So, this part works in my code. And my local database also. But I do not know how to integrate my data from my database in ma App file.

I use the react navigation and want to integrate the data from the database for example in my Stack.Screen.

How can I integrate the data in my code?

```
function DetailsScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      
    </View>
  );
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function StackScreen() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen 
      name="HEADER" 
      component={DetailsScreen} 
      options={{
        headerTitle: props => <LogoTitle {...props} />,
        title: 'Website of Peter Pan',
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: '#00A1DE',
          opacity: '100%'
        },
        headerTintColor: '#fff',
      }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator
      tabBarOptions={{
         activeTintColor: '#fff',
         inactiveTintColor: 'lightgray',
             style: {
                   backgroundColor: '#00A1DE', 
                   
             }
      }}
      screenOptions = {({route}) => ({
        tabBarIcon:({color, size}) => {
          let iconName; 
          if (route.name =='Home') {
            iconName='ios-home'
          } else if (route.name == 'User') {
            iconName='people'
          }
          return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={size} color= {color} />
        }
      })}
      >
        <Tab.Screen 
        name="Home"
        component={StackScreen} 
          />
        <Tab.Screen name="User" 
        component={StackScreen} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

EDIT:

I did this:

```
export default class App extends Component {

state = {
  data: [], 
}

componentWillMount() {
  this.fetchData(); 

}

fetchData = async () => {
  const response = await fetch('http://MYownIP/TABLENAME'); 
  const json = await response.json(); 
  this.setState({data: json.results}); 
}

render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <FlatList 
            data = {this.state.data}
            keyExtractor={(x, i) => i}
            renderItem={({item}) =>
             <Text> {item.TableATTRIBUTNAME}
             </Text>}
              />
        </View>
    );
}
```

}

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        marginTop: 15, 
        flex: 1, 
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center', 
        backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF"
    }
});
```

but it does not work. It shows nothing in the screen. But when I use https://randomuser.me/api?results=10 instead of my own IP in the fetch function, then it works and I can see 10 names at the screen.
But localhost:3000/tablename in the browser works also, so the database is active. I dont know, where the issue is. Do you?

FOUND THE SOLUTION:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
```

res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
next();
});

adding this route.js
after
const app = express();

from: https://dzone.com/articles/cors-in-node

Comment: Can you take a look at your browser console? Does it give any error message?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your API returns data in JSON format, you can use map-function in React:

[Rendering JSON API in react Using map method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48250294/rendering-json-api-in-react-using-map-method)

Edit: You might need to use `JSON.stringify(this.state.data)` in order to convert data into string before rendering.

Comment: but the syntax from native react and react js are different. I dont know how to translate it to native react...